# How to use C++ api in nodejs?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-ffi

I would like to use the C++ API of a project from Node and I can't change the C++ code.
I looked at node-ffi but it doesn't seems to be able to work with C++ namespace and classes.

Do you know any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG can wrap c++ for many scripting languages, including javascript/nodejs. See http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html

Comment: I was able to build a `.cxx` with SWIG but got path resolution problems when using `node-gyp`. The cc file include `#include "kudu/client/client.pb.h"` but this path is valid when the root folder is different.

Comment: Compilers can be told where to search for headers. See the documentation of your compiler.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to include it in binding.gyp.